# BlueJ arrays "array required"

Tags: java, arrays

When I compile my code below I get the error

> array required, but `java.util.ArrayList<int[]>` found at line `"atoms[index] = atoms.get(index) + atom "`

Can anyone please tell me what I've done wrong?

```
public void makeMolecular()
{
    ArrayList <char[]> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <int[]> atoms = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Term> result = new ArrayList();
    int i=0;
    for(Term term : terms ){
        char element = term.element;
        int atom = term.atoms;
        int index = elements.indexOf(element);
        if (elements.contains(element)){
            atoms[index] = atoms.get(index) + atom;
        } else {
            elements.add(element);
            atoms.add(atom);
        }
    }
    for (char element : elements){
        Term term = new Term(element,atoms.get(i));
        i++;
        result.add(term);
    }
    this.term = result;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with JavaScript when it is purely a Java question?

Comment: cos im a noob, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array notation `[index]` with ArrayLists. The proper code would be:

`atoms.set(index, atoms.get(index) + atom);`

Comment: thank you, but my error is now saying "bad operand type for binary operator '+'
first type: int[];         second type: int

Comment: Looks like you also need to change `ArrayList <int[]> atoms = new ArrayList();` to `ArrayList <Integer> atoms = new ArrayList();` since you are storing Integer values in the ArrayList, not arrays of integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
if (elements.contains(element)){
    atoms[index] = atoms.get(index) + atom;
```

makes no sense...
**atom is an int** and **atoms is a list of arrays containing ints**

you can't just do that addition between them

and at last since atoms is an `arrayList`, this `atoms[index]` is not correct, you are trying to access the elements as they were an Array.

that  is the reason why the code in not working...

Comment: thank you, i understand what you are saying, but I am not sure how to convert it all to an int, if that is even possible, or if i should have it all as an array to proceed. could you please walk me through the coding?